# @RequestBody on a Rest method

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a controller with a lot of methods where I receive a simple property as data, like

```
-d '{ "email": "rostany.sabater@gmail.com" }'
```

for all this methods I create a class with a simple property:

```
@RequestBody MyClass myClass
```

, and I wonder if there is a simple way to do it instead of creating a lot of classes for a simple property

Comment: You can probably use a `Map<String, String>` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments you can use a map as its json which is k,v pairs

or

to keep it clean and organised why not create a generic class which has a list of  in this format `[{"key":"k0","value":"v0"},{"key":"k1","value":"v1"}]`

e.g. URI is `/baseri?requestVariableLong=[{"key":"k0","value":"v0"},{"key":"k1","value":"v1"}]`

i.e. JSON representation of the `List<MyClass> class` as shown below

```
class MyClass{
    String key;
    String value;
// constructors 
//getters
//setters
}
```

In one line of code below you can convert query parameter MyClass in to List

```
new Gson().fromJson(requestVariableLong,MyClass.class);
```

you can iterate over list which will be dynamic and do whatever you want....